# XAMPP problem MAC address and HV_error not detected

Tags: macos

Cannot calculate MAC address: Using fd 7 for I/O notifications
hv_vm_create HV_ERROR (unspecified error)

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2g

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1: Take a backup of your current files**

```
cp -rp ~/.bitnami ~/.bitnami.back
```

**STEP 2: Download the new hyperkit binary**

```
cd /tmp

curl -LJO "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/hyperkit/hyperkit-testing-20210430"
```

**STEP 3: Ensure that the md5 checksum matches with this one**

```
md5 /tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430
```

Results => MD5 (/tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430) = 37495adde6a3279dd7265904b85c3dc9

*Warning: Do not continue with the next step if the md5 checksum doesn’t match*

**STEP 4: Replace your current hyperkit binary with the downloaded one**

```
mv /tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430 ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit
chmod +x ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit
```

CREDITS : https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-wordpress-mac-os-11-3-big-sur-error-starting-wordpress-stack/94776/9

For more information please refer the above link

Comment: It's working for me but where I can get my backup? because it's complete setup the new xampp.